# Unity - How to Anchor to an Object if it Collides With a Child Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have a telescoping spike gadget in a game that I'm working on. The spike is supposed to be an arm attachment for the player which will allow them to stick to a wall once the spike tip (the deepest child object) touches something. Essentially I want it to "stab" into the wall and hold the player in place.

The closest I've gotten to this has been by setting "Contact Pairs Mode" to "Enable Kinematic Kinematic Pairs", then adding a kinematic RigidBody and a FixedJoint to the tip. Here is the code for the spike itself:

```
private IEnumerator _ExpandSequence()
    {
        mExpanding = true;
        if (mCollapsing)
        {
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => !mCollapsing);
        }

        mBaseGoal = transform.localPosition + mBaseDistance * Vector3.up;
        mConeGoal = mSpikeSections[5].localPosition + mConeDistance * Vector3.up;

        while (transform.localPosition.y > mBaseSpikeEnd || mSpikeSections[1].localPosition.y > mCylinderEnd
            || mSpikeSections[5].localPosition.y > mConeEnd)
        { //only using the first cylinder section in the condition since they all move the same distance
            
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, mBaseGoal, mSpeed);

            mSpikeSections[1].localPosition = mSpikeSections[2].localPosition = mSpikeSections[3].localPosition = 
                mSpikeSections[4].localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mSpikeSections[1].localPosition, Vector3.up * mCylinderDistance, mSpeed);

            mSpikeSections[5].localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(mSpikeSections[5].localPosition, mConeGoal, mSpeed);

            if (Mathf.Approximately(transform.localPosition.y, mBaseSpikeEnd) &&
                Mathf.Approximately(mSpikeSections[1].localPosition.y, mCylinderEnd) &&
                Mathf.Approximately(mSpikeSections[5].localPosition.y, mConeEnd))
            {
                transform.localPosition = mBaseGoal;
                mSpikeSections[5].localPosition = mConeGoal;
                break;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
        mExpanding = false;
        mExtended = true;
    }
```

Here is the code for the spike tip's collision:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || col.gameObject.tag == "Environment")
        {
            //Anchor            
            mFj.connectedBody = col.rigidbody;
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

And here is the hierarchy for the player's assets:
[image]

Currently when the spike collides with a surface, I can see in the editor that a connected body is registered
[image]

Despite this, the player bounces off and is able to move freely as if the joint didn't exist. Can anyone help me find out why the player isn't being fixed to the wall?

TL;DR: How can I get a child object with a RigidBody to connect to another object via a FixedJoint?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your first question. Also you can always ask me for an example before voting. How does voting to close my issue help me?

Comment: Information has been updated and code has been added

Comment: I'm still unsure how the player is moved in your situation. Anyway, assuming the player has a rigidbody that you are using, try connecting the tip and player rigidbodies with a suitable joint.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes the player has a rigidbody as well. However I'm not sure what you mean by "a suitable joint", or how connecting the player to the tip (which is already a child object) would make the player stick to a surface

Comment: forces applied to child rigidbodies do not impart forces to parent rigidbodies unless they have direct or indirect collider contact or have joints between them.

Comment: I've added another screenshot of the player hierarchy. Would you mind suggesting a type of joint and where to add it?

Comment: fixed joint on the tip connected to the player rb might be what you need, depending what you exactly mean by "anchor". Otherwise, please edit the question to describe the desired behavior in more detail. depending on that, you may want a configurable joint, and maybe more than one. [e.g.](https://answers.unity.com/questions/22159/how-do-i-create-a-chain-using-joints-and-rigidbodi.html)

Comment: You had a point about the desired behavior, so I edited it. Hopefully it will be more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create two FixedJoint components on the tip and assign them to fields in the script. Assign the rigidbody of the player to a field in the script. Assign the rigidbody and collider of the tip to a field in the script.

Second, when the collision occurs, turn isKinematic off, so that the tip affects and is affected by joints (e.g., so it follows anchoredenemies if they move)

Third, when you want to end the anchor, you should just be able to set isKinematic to true again, assign both of its joint connected bodies to null, and if necessary disable its collider to avoid

```
[SerializeField] FixedJoint mFixedJointTarget; // 1st fixed joint on tip
[SerializeField] FixedJoint mFixedJointPlayer; // 2nd fixed joint on tip

[SerializeField] Rigidbody myRB;     // rigidbody of tip
[SerializeField] Rigidbody playerRB; // player's rigidbody

[SerializeField] Collider myColl; // if necessary to avoid re-attachment

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || col.gameObject.tag == "Environment")
    {
        StartAnchor(col.rigidbody); 
    }
}

void StartAnchor(Rigidbody targetRB)
{
    myRB.isKinematic = false;

    mFixedJointTarget.connectedBody = targetRB;
    mFixedJointPlayer.connectedBody = playerRB;
}

void StopAnchor()
{
    myRB.isKinematic = true;
    mFixedJointTarget.connectedBody = null;
    mFixedJointPlayer.connectedBody = null;

    // re-enable before shooting again, of course
    // may not be necessary depending on what else you do when you stop anchoring.
    myColl.enabled = false;
}
```

---

You can do the same with the tip never being kinematic if you would like, you will just need to `Destroy` the joints instead of setting the `connectedBody`s to null, and also create the joints *only* when a collision occurs, this might look like the following:

```
//on drill with useGravity = false
public class DrillShot : MonoBehaviour
{
    FixedJoint mFixedJointTarget; // 1st fixed joint on tip
    FixedJoint mFixedJointPlayer; // 2nd fixed joint on tip

    Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody playerRB; // player's rigidbody

    Renderer rend;

    [SerializeField] float speed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || col.gameObject.tag == "Environment")
        {
            StartAnchor(col.rigidbody);
        }
    }

    void StartAnchor(Rigidbody targetRB)
    {
        if (mFixedJointTarget != null)
        {
            Destroy(mFixedJointTarget);
        }

        if (mFixedJointPlayer != null)
        {
            Destroy(mFixedJointPlayer);
        }

        mFixedJointPlayer = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        mFixedJointPlayer.connectedBody = playerRB;

        mFixedJointTarget = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();
        mFixedJointTarget.connectedBody = targetRB;
    }

    void StopAnchor()
    {
        if (mFixedJointTarget != null)
        {
            Destroy(mFixedJointTarget);
        }

        if (mFixedJointPlayer != null)
        {
            Destroy(mFixedJointPlayer);
        }

        rend.enabled = false;
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        rend.enabled = true;
        transform.position = playerRB.position + Vector3.right;

        rb.velocity = Vector3.right * speed;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            StopAnchor();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// on wall, with rigidbody tagged "Environment",
// xyz freeze rotation mass 100, use gravity = false
public class MoveRandomly : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 curTarget;
    Vector3 startPos;

    [SerializeField] float switchTargetPeriod = 2f;
    [SerializeField] float targetRadius = 1f;
    [SerializeField] float dampener = 0.05f;
    Rigidbody rb;
    float t = 0f;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        t -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (t < 0)
        {
            t = switchTargetPeriod;
            curTarget = startPos + Random.insideUnitSphere * targetRadius;
        }

        Vector3 diff = curTarget - transform.position;
        rb.AddForce(diff * dampener, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

[image: Player inspector/hierarchy]
[image: Drill inspector/hierarchy]
[image: Wall inspector/hierarchy]

[image: demo of use]

Comment: Incredible, this seems to work! There's a little "wonkiness" from the spike sections moving out of place, but I believe that's due to the spike animation being driven by a coroutine and the tip being made non-kinematic before this finishes. I'm certain if I can make all this code happen afterwards, it will fix everything. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: @AlWil Glad I could help. If you find any improvements consider editing this answer to help future visitors with the same problem :)

Comment: Okay I may have marked this as solved a little too soon. With your code, the tip is drifting a lot, both messing with the animations and causing the player to slowly slip. I tried keeping it kinematic the whole time, which worked better in most cases, but caused the player to jitter violently if the spike stuck too far into a wall

Comment: @AlWil I included enough code to reproduce what works for me. Hopefully that helps.